# splint: parse error in for loop

Tags: c, static-analysis, splint

I am using splint as static analyzer for c99 code.

Splint seems to be not quite c99 compliant. Thus I have applied this patch:
http://www.cs.virginia.edu/pipermail/splint-discuss/attachments/20080718/52cc25f6/attachment.obj

Now I get no **parse errors** due to declarations not beeing on top.

But I still get **parse errors** in for loops, if I put in the for statement a variable declaration.
For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
}
```

A workaround is to write it like this:

```
int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    }
```

But as I dont want to adapt all my for loops, I am wondering if there is a patch available which solves this issue.

Comment: If there isn't I really hope you do not modify your code just to make splint happy.

Comment: I dont get your comment.

Comment: Well, that you rather ignore the complaints from splint instead of modifying your code to keep it happy even though it makes your code actually worse.

Comment: That is not helping, because it is not a warning by splint, it is a parse error. Thus it stops processing my code.

Comment: Then I'd consider not using splint at all - it's clearly outdated.

Comment: If splint can't tell valid C from invalid C, it certainly can't be trusted to tell _good_ valid C from _bad_ valid C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is no answer yet, I just quote the wikipedia article on splint [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splint_%28programming_tool%29)

> Recent development activity on Splint has slowed significantly.
>   According to the CVS at SourceForge, as of January 2009 the most
>   recent change in the repository was in August 2008. The whole year
>   2008 had only two write accesses to the repository. The maintainer has
>   said that development is stagnant and the project needs new
>   volunteers.

Since declaring variables in the loop head is C99 compliant ( and argueable preferable style ), you should refrain from splint until this is fixed.